# How can I get a list of items that is part of an object?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-extensions

I have something like this:

```
class SomeClass 
{
     public int Id {get;set}
     public int someProperty1 {get;set;}
     public int someProperty2 {get;set;}
     public string someProperty3 {get;set;}
     public List<SomeObject> SomeObjects {get;set}
}
```

When I want to get properties of this class, I do:

```
var db = new SomeClass();
var myClass = db.SomeClass.Single(class => class.Id == 1);
```

And it works perfectly fine, I can get all the properties, but the `List<SomeObject>` property is always null. How can I get a single `myClass` object, that does have all the properties, AND a list of `SomeObject`s? I know that I can do it like that:

```
var myList = db.SomeClass.SomeObjects.Single(...);
```

But I do not want to do it that way, is there any other way of getting WHOLE object at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework, you can **include** a related table using the Include method. See the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx).

```
var db = new Context();
var myClass = db.SomeClass.Include("SomeObject").Single(class => class.Id == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are making a new object for `SomeClass`
Have you assigned values to its properties?

like

```
var db = new SomeClass();
db.Id=1;
db.someProperty1 = 1;
db.someProperty2 = 2;
db.someProperty3 = "abc";
db.SomeObjects = objListOfSomeObject //list reference of SomeObject
```

Or anywhere else you have defined these ?

and how can you call `db.SomeClass` ?

Comment: you should edit your question var db = new SomeClass();
to db = new Context();